# How to pass a user's password to puppeteer inside a Firebase callable function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

How do I pass in a user's email & password into a function from a Firebase callable function?

I have written a callable function that uses puppeteer to navigate to a user's dashboard page, make a PDF of it, and then store the PDF in Cloud Storage.

My problem is that users must be authenticated to view the page. Without providing authentication, puppeteer just takes a PDF of my login page.

If I hard code in an email and password and toss it to puppeteer like so, then I get the desired dashboard page:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

  

  await page.goto("https:www.somepage.com/auth/signin", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  email = context.auth.token.email;
  password = "myPassword";


  await page.type("[type=email]", email);
  await page.type("[type=password]", password);
  await page.click("[type=submit");

  await page.waitFor(5000);

  await page.goto("https:www.somepage.com/dashboard", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });
```

I know how to retrieve the current user's email from context, but how do I retrieve the password as well? Is this even possible?

Or, is there a better way to go about this altogether?

I've tried using context and admin, but have read that this is the wrong approach or just plain not possible.

Thank you for any help you can provide and sorry if this question has been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get a users plaintext, unhashed password from Firebase Auth.  That's considered a security problem.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! I was hoping to get the hashed password and that passing the hashed password to puppeteer would work. Is that not so?

Comment: Or, is there a way to just tell puppeteer that a user is already authenticated by using context?

Comment: A hashed password would not work if provided to a login form that is normally used for user sign-in.  The best you can do is somehow inject an ID token for the user into the page.

Comment: @MikeDyer, I have an almost identical problem. Have you uncovered anything that works?

I'm thinking about storing the user's credentials in Firestore, encrypting the password in the user's document and decrypting it on the way out when the function collects the data it needs. (I have no clue if this is possible . . . or even if it's a good idea.)

Comment: I ended up just getting the data from Firestore and making a template with handlebars and using puppeteer to make the pdf. No need to mess around with auth.